# How do I implement merge sort on an array of ints?

Tags: c++, arrays, mergesort

I have an assignment that asks for an array of one million `int`s to be sorted using merge sort. The way I learned merge sort was with a split routine and a merge routine, using recursion. How would I split an array using recursion? Would I need to make a total of three arrays, two of them half the size of the original?

I may not be making myself clear, because I am confused about the whole concept right now.

I don't know how to code in Python, and I do not know what trimsort is.

Comment: Wikipedia has a great overview of merge sort: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort

Comment: possible duplicate of [fast, clean, C, timsort implementation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556935/fast-clean-c-timsort-implementation)

Comment: @Lance - I think that's a little harsh. This isn't the usual "plz send teh codez" homework question, he's actually thought about it, has proposed an approach and is seeking peer review.

Comment: @Lance: This is not quite true. Stack Overflow is great for homework questions, as long as the asker follows the rules, in particular show effort, be specific, not ask for "teh codez" but for explanation and help. In addition, the asker is advised to make sure that his school/teacher are okay with help from outside sources, and even if he gets code in response, to study it, understand it, and write his own based on said understanding in order to avoid plagiarism. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: honestly, shortest example I can think of (at least for the algorithm) exploits the standard library significantly. [see it live](http://ideone.com/50k5po)

Comment: @WhozCraig - that's a big problem with helping students. I have Knuth 1-3 on my shelf and I've read them. I even understand most of it, but if OP said to me how would you sort a million anything the answer would be "with an index in a database". Yet knowing how it all works is vital because it informs both the choices we make and interpretation of debug info.

Comment: You don't need several arrays, instead you can use pointers (or iterators) into the original array to mark the beginnings and ends of the sub-arrays.

Answer (score 3):

For doing merge sort sequentially you should do following things in your recursive function:

1. check the size of your array: if it is less or equal to 2, sort the
           array and return it.
2. Split your array in two parts and call the recursive function for each half.
3. Merge the result of two  sorted arrays, that are coming from function calls from step 2.

The size of input is not actually important for how you solve it, unless you want to do it in parallel.

Comment: Thank you! You answered most of my question. I am still uncertain of how I could possibly split an array in half without having to re-size the original array.

Comment: In addition, you can have two strategies regarding the subarrays: you can allocate new arrays (easier but more space-consuming), or you can do everything in-place with a creative use of swaps (which is how most people would do it in any language that allows mutable arrays, such as C is). In the latter case, you typically have something like `merge_sort(array, start, end)`, which will call itself with `start` to `mid`, and again with `mid+1` to `end` (where `mid` is `(start + end) / 2`)

Comment: so making three total arrays would be a waste then? This just seems easier, since I don't have to worry about memory in this case.

Comment: @SamPerales doing it without a new array is better in case of memory space, but merging part without using an extra array, needs more computation because of shifting the elements to their right place, so its kind of tradeoff between computation and memory usage.

Comment: @SamPerales honestly two arrays are sufficient (and frankly the easiest to code); the array being sorted, and one matching sized array for temp storage. In-place algorithms exist, but are considerably more complicated than most people think (a "practical" algorithm, term used loosely, [can be seen here](http://akira.ruc.dk/~keld/teaching/algoritmedesign_f04/Artikler/04/Huang88.pdf)).

Answer (score 0):

Merge sort on an array of 10000 ints is done in the same way as it is done on 4 elements.  Divide and conquer.

Comment: this confuses me deeply, care to elaborate?

Comment: In recursion you define a base case(the smallest array that your algorithm can work on) and continually call the recursive method on smaller parts of the array until you are at you base case.  If you are unfamiliar with recursion this will be difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you don't actually 'split' the array, per se, as that would be wasteful to create two more sub-arrays in memory. The splitting is more of a visually intuitive way to think about it.

Instead what you do is treat the array like it consists of two or more parts. If you think about how you reference parts of an array in memory, especially when you pass a handle to them into a function, you're typically dealing with a pointer to the address of the first element in the array combined with something else to keep track of the end of the array (typically like a size integral).

So we can do something like this to simulate a 'split':

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

static void left_side(int* ptr, int size)
{
    cout << "left side:";
    for (int j=0; j < size; ++j)
        cout << " " << ptr[j];
    cout << endl;
}

static void right_side(int* ptr, int size)
{
    cout << "right side:";
    for (int j=0; j < size; ++j)
        cout << " " << ptr[j];
    cout << endl;
}

static void split(int* ptr, int size)
{
    const int middle_index = size / 2;
    left_side(ptr, middle_index);
    right_side(ptr + middle_index, size - middle_index);
}

int main()
{
    int x[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    split(x, 5);
}

// output:
// left side: 1 2
// right side: 3 4 5
```

That should help you get started and clear things up a bit about what 'split' actually means in this context. As you can see, we're not actually creating any new 'sub-arrays', we're simply treating the existing single array as though it has multiple parts to it.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful! The only issue I am having is with the `static void split(int* ptr, int size)` especially the recursive call for `right_side(ptr + middle, size - middle);` how does `ptr + middle` work exactly?

Comment: `ptr + middle` actually offsets that pointer by whatever that middle value is. In the case of 5 elements, 5 / 2 = 2 (integer division is truncated).

So initially you have ptr, size pointing to the first element of the array with a size of 5. You then compute this middle index, 2, and then pass in the pointer to the first element with a size of 2 for the left side.

For the right side, you pass in the pointer to the first element shifted by 2 elements, so you're effectively passing a pointer to the third element with a size of 3 (third, fourth, and fifth) elements.

Comment: So basically you're treating one array like it has two parts. ptr=array_start_address, size=2 for the first and second elements of the left side. Then ptr=array_start_address+2, size=3 for the third, fourth, and fith elements of the right side.

Comment: I see, I have the split routine for a linked list, but my assignment asked for an array, and I couldn't grasp the idea of splitting an array with a set size and all. So in the recursive call for the `right_side(ptr + middle, size - middle)`, in my case, the call will cut the million `int` s in half, until the base case gets reached, which is if the array has two elements. right?

Comment: It's worth remembering that pointers just store addresses in memory. You can think of them visually like arrows moving around this giant linear block of memory. The pointer isn't the array, the pointer is simply pointing to the first element of the array. So you're allowed to move it around all over the place, and 'splitting' in this context isn't really splitting memory blocks but simply splitting the range of memory addresses you're working with into two parts using pointer arithmetic.

Comment: Yes, the base case is when you have just two elements, and sorting two elements is just a single swap at most (or it could already be sorted if the left element is less than the right). Then you just descend down the call stack from that point and start merging the already sorted lists with a single linear pass through the left list and right list until you work your way back down to a fully sorted list.

Comment: Also you can have a base case when you reach one element (one or two). If it's one, do nothing, if it's two, swap if the first element is greater than the second. Handling the one element case is necessary since a list (addressing range) of 3 elements divides into a list (addressing range) of one element and a list of two elements.

Comment: If I divide 1,000,000 by 2, I will get 500,000. So is `array[500,000]` the end of my left side? And `array[500,001]` the start of my right side?

Comment: The left side will be a pointer to array with a size of 500,000. The right side will be a pointer to an array + 500,000 with a size of 500,000.

Comment: Like this: 
const int num=1000000;
int my_array[num]={...}; 
int* left_ptr=array; 
int left_num=num/2;
int* right_ptr=array+num/2;
int right_num=size-num/2; In this case, both left and right side will have a size of 500,000, since 1 mil divides evenly.

Comment: Yeah this makes sense now, I didn't know I had this power, thanks @Ike you were very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Using library code...

Call std::sort on each array.
Then call std::merge on the two arrays

If you're exercise is to write your own, then ignore this answer.